# how to get first character of second string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to get first 2 character of string in javascript like this "Hello world " => get this "wo"?
another example
"Osama Mohamed" => M.

Comment: Is your second example really what you want? If it is a name there should be no quotes and only the first letter followed by a dot?

Comment: yes that i want

Comment: Do you have a list of names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I can't see what rule would give you `"wo"` for `"Hello world"` but `"M"` or `"M."` for `"Osama Mohamed"`. But it doesn't really matter, the question is too broad.

Comment: yes and i want to extract from it

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any of this information. It should. Explaining what you want in the comments is not sufficient.

Comment: shouldn't it give you 'w' from "Hello world"?

Comment: On what basis should it be decided whether the second letter should be replaced by a 'dot'? Randomness?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `string.split(' ')`, this function will split you string into an array, for example:

```
let s = "Hello World";
console.log(s.split(" ")) // will log ["Hello", "World"]
```

then you can get the second word using `array[index]` when index the index of your desired word in said array.

now using string `charAt` we can get the first letter of the word.

now to put everything together:

```js
let s = "Hello World"
let s_splited = s.split(" ") // ["Hello", "World"]
let second_word = s_splited[1]
console.log(second_word.charAt(0))
```

Comment: 1. The Question owner would like `wo` isntead of `w` and 2. What is with the case of `Osama Mohamed` ?

Comment: He didn't quite clear that. But i believe that this should give him the basis to achieve whatever he wants

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Hello world";
split_string = string.split(" ");
second_word = split_string[1]
first_char = second_word[0]
console.log(first_char)
```

OR

```
string = "Hello world";
console.log(string.split(" ")[1][0])
```